# How to create a sequence of signals and stop the sequence after a certain amount of occurrences

Tags: go

I want to have a certain number `N` of signals separated by a defined interval `T`.

For this I use the `ticker` type and a counter like this

```
func main() {
    N := 10
    T := 100 * time.Millisecond
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(T)
    done := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    count := 0
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                wg.Done()
                return
            case t := <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
                count++
                if count == N {
                    done <- struct{}{}
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    ticker.Stop()

    fmt.Println("DONE")
}
```

This implementation seems to work (here the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/D9lVwwAboxZ)) but I am not convinced of signalling on the `done` channel from within the `select` where the same `done` channel is used and I am wondering whether there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think you can just close done channel. And then read from done will succeed. (Closed channel always return default value)

Comment: You could also skip the wg altogether by waiting one `<-done` outside the go routine.

Comment: example of closing done https://go.dev/play/p/3lCEKKE-oKp
example of using done for waiting https://go.dev/play/p/m9A4xdP-zQ_n

Comment: @moficodes Thanks for your suggestion. I can actually skip the wg. On the other hand your [last example](https://go.dev/play/p/m9A4xdP-zQ_n) I think has a problem: if you remove the `case <- done` from the `select` then the goroutine never exits as you can see in [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/8WLHOcgJsW6)